# Generating a C header file from an XML schema using Python script

Tags: python, c, xml, parsing

As the title says, I need to write a Python script that generates a C header file from an XML schema.

Can anyone please point me to a good tool that could automatically generate a C header file from an XML schema or show me an example project where a Python script was written to parse an XML file to output a C file?

I have done a lot of googling but I only find results for doing the opposite (C file to XML).

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using `PyXb` and `Cheetah Template Engine`.

**Step 1:**

Assuming you have a XML schema file (`.xsd`) you can use `PyXb` to translate the schema file to Python objects or data bindings. Check [PyXb](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/) and this [link](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/userref_pyxbgen.html) which demonstrates how to generate Python bindings from XML schema.

**Step 2:**

Once you get your Python objects/bindings, you can use a Template Engine to use Python objects to generate the C source. One recommendation would be [Cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/). You need to write a template file (`some.tmpl`) which contains semantics of how your C code will look like. This template will be input to Cheetah to generate the final C code.

[Cheetah user guide](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/docs/users_guide_html/)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for getting back to me. I will try your solution and update on the outcome.